# Python: is function inside loop good practice or not

Tags: python

It's pretty handy that we can define functions anywhere in Python. But is it a good practice to define functions inside a loop? Will it cause any unnecessary overhead during runtime?

Comment: Well, yes, because the function is re-created each time. Why do it?

Comment: would be better to define outside the loop and pass loop variables as arguments

Comment: Without a specific example you cannot say. There are some reasons why you would put a function definition in a loop, but only do it if it is necessary

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ just want to make the code concise, got too many variables to be passed to the function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @cs95 has pointed out, the function is re-created each time, which can be seen with `dis.dis`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> code = """
... for i in range(3):
...     def foo(j):
...         print(j)
...     foo(i)
... """
>>> dis.dis(code)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              32 (to 34)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (3)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                20 (to 32)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (i)
  3          14 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object foo at 0x107544810, file "<dis>", line 3>)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo')
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             20 STORE_NAME               2 (foo)
  5          22 LOAD_NAME                2 (foo)
             24 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             28 POP_TOP
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
```

As @avigil suggested, it would be better to define the function outside the loop and pass loop variables as arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!